# NodeJS HTTP сервер на 80 порту (Linux)

Tags: linux, http, веб-сервер, portforwarding

Да, чтобы забиндить порт < 1024 на Linux требуются рут-права. Поэтому, если я запущу следующий скрипт с помощью команды `sudo node script.js`, то сервер будет слушать 80 порт.

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(80);
```

Теперь мне нужно поднять сервер с помощью [PubSubHubbub](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/node-pubsubhubbub). Если запустить [пример](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/node-pubsubhubbub/blob/master/examples/example.js) из самого репо с рут-правами, то сервер не будет доступен "снаружи", т.е. обратиться к нему я смогу только локально.
Код, который поднимает сервер в данной библиотеке:

```
PubSubHubbub.prototype.listen = function(port){
    this.port = port;

    this.server = http.createServer(this._onRequest.bind(this));
    this.server.on("error", this._onError.bind(this));
    this.server.on("listening", this._onListening.bind(this));

    this.server.listen(this.port);
}
```

Почему при поднятии сервера в библиотеке невозможно забиндить порт "глобально", даже при запуске самого скрипта с рут-правами?